# SQL Server deadlock on select

Tags: python, sql-server

I created a multi process crawler and it has to send many transactions to find out each record is new or not, but sometimes I get a deadlock error in SQL Server but I can not understand the reason because they are both select commands, however I have many insert requests as well but they don't have anything to do with older data, those commands just insert new data.

Any idea on why it is happening ?

```
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="process1f40203f468" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="process1f40203f468" taskpriority="0" logused="276" waitresource="PAGE: 7:1:12748 " waittime="2944" ownerId="817317" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2020-06-13T21:56:06.487" XDES="0x1f3ef94c490" lockMode="S" schedulerid="5" kpid="17220" status="suspended" spid="65" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2020-06-13T21:56:06.513" lastbatchcompleted="2020-06-13T21:56:06.510" lastattention="2020-06-13T21:56:06.487" clientapp="pymssql=2.1.4" hostname="DESKTOP-..." hostpid="17140" loginname="crawler" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="817317" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671090784" clientoption2="128060">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="812" sqlhandle="0x020000009deb501d1126fcd95ce07de6f9476a44b49b12960000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
SELECT TOP 1 ...
FROM [x] 
WHERE [x].[y] = 9 AND [x].[z] = 4 AND [x].[t] = 9   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="process1f3f2941848" taskpriority="0" logused="276" waitresource="PAGE: 7:1:12748 " waittime="2946" ownerId="817315" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2020-06-13T21:56:06.487" XDES="0x1f3f73e8490" lockMode="S" schedulerid="4" kpid="4308" status="suspended" spid="64" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2020-06-13T21:56:06.513" lastbatchcompleted="2020-06-13T21:56:06.510" lastattention="2020-06-13T21:56:06.483" clientapp="pymssql=2.1.4" hostname="DESKTOP-..." hostpid="17140" loginname="crawler" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="817315" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671090784" clientoption2="128060">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtend="812" sqlhandle="0x0200000028ce610d87acf007408107c69b899291c35585460000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
SELECT TOP 1 ...
FROM [x] 
WHERE [x].[y] = 5 AND [x].[z] = 9 AND [x].[t] = 9   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="12748" dbid="7" subresource="FULL" objectname="..." id="lock1f402553180" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594049527808">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process1f3f2941848" mode="IX" />
    <owner id="process1f3f2941848" mode="S" requestType="convert" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process1f40203f468" mode="S" requestType="convert" />
   </waiter-list>
  </pagelock>
  <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="12748" dbid="7" subresource="FULL" objectname="..." id="lock1f402553180" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594049527808">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="process1f40203f468" mode="IX" />
    <owner id="process1f40203f468" mode="S" requestType="convert" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="process1f3f2941848" mode="S" requestType="convert" />
   </waiter-list>
  </pagelock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: That is odd.  Please post the python code in your question and the table definition.  You can certianly aviod this by changing the database to READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT or using SNAPSHOT isolation.  But It would be better to get to the bottom of this.  Ensure you have AUTOCOMMIT on to avoid accumulating locks between statements.  https://pythonhosted.org/pymssql/ref/pymssql.html

Comment: Also "Microsoft places its testing efforts and its confidence in pyodbc driver." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: The `SELECT` commands are doing data modifications in other statements earlier in the same transaction and retaining locks from those. If it was just a select statement on its own you wouldn't see `logused="276"`

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks for your advice, but i can not publish the code to the public

Comment: @MartinSmith what can i do to avoid this? in my app, there are many threads/process (generated by a dispatcher) that create an instance from `AppContext` class (that i pass the class type as an argument) in which i create a `session` using `scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=client))` `client=create_engine(...)`. and submit some` select` (or maybe `insert` queries when new data comes up) and when a thread comes to its end it calls `session.close()` and `client.dispose()`. Should i do any modification in structure to fix this issue ?